# How to add custom field in the content type of Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I want to add a custom field which value will come from external API. As example values may be:

```
array(
     'v1'=>'value1'
     'v2'=>'value2'
     'v3'=>'value3'
)
```

So, I want to display them in a dropdown menu as field in the content-type article.

Answer (score 0):

I don't it is right answer, but as per my view it is not better to store all values of third party DB.

To achive your goal I will do like this.

Content type Article which include another two fields:

- Number field: Id (api_db_id) : v1, v2, v3....
- Text Field: Value (api_db_value) E.g: value 1, value 2 ...

These above field will be hidden.

Before render form E.g: by using hook_form_alter we can connect to third party API and get values and populate in select list

E.g:

```
function myhook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if($form_id == 'article'){

    /*

    Third Party API connection code which will generate $dropdown_array.

     */

    $options = $dropdown_array;
      // Alter form
      $form['title'] = array(     
         '#type' => 'select',
         '#default_value' => '1',// set default value.        
         '#options' => $options,
      ); 

   }//endif
}
```

**And Final step will before submit form we will assign selected ID and value to our new field .**

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom module to implement your field.
A good tutorial can be found [HERE](https://clikfocus.com/blog/how-to-set-up-custom-field-type-using-drupal-7-fields-api).
You can check out version 7 of the [examples module](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples), specifically the [field_example](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/field_example?h=7.x-1.x) which has very good documentation in the code.
Once you get your head around how it (the hooks) works, there really isn't all that much code to write.

Doing it this way is probably much better than trying to alter other types of fields, and it should automatically integrate with views as expected.